# Android sms with link to application or Google play

Tags: android, hyperlink, sms, deep-linking

I am trying to create an application that will send sms with link to the following:
If application already installed on the phone, the link will open it.
If the app is not installed, the link will open Google play store on the app page...

Comment: Google Deep linking in android .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex: Your link will be something like **https://example.com** and you have the intent filter in Android Manifest as below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.droid.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Use the **URL Mapping** editor to easily add URL intent filters to your Activities with Android App Links (Android Studio > Tools > Android App Links).

Answer (score 0):

Provide your Application web Url with the SMS.

In that page Redirect to Playstore.

In Your Application Create [DeepLink](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) with that Your URL

Whenever the URL is Encountered the Application will be opened if it is installed. Otherwise, it will redirect to the Play store from the page.

You Can use the Playstore Url of App. But It is not recommended since playstore and other store application may also catch the same link.

[DeepLinking In Android Application](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

### Example

```
<activity
    android:name="com.package.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="weburl"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```